# how can I redirect the user to Setting -> Security -> Notification Access in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

6

I'm currently developing an app for Android that uses the `NotificationListenerService`, which requires that the user will enable notification access for my app under `Setting -> Security -> Notification Access`.

My question is that can I redirect the user to this place so they will enable it? So far I only managed to direct them to `Setting -> Security` window.

Also, is it possible to first check if the user enabled notification access for my app already and only then redirect them?

Answer (score 3):

For Flutter

After a long search, I found the solution that will show the intended notification settings.

This is only for Flutter.

I found an [app_settings](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) plugin. Just add it in pubspec.yaml and install it.

After that just one line of code.

```
RaisedButton(

                onPressed: () {
                  // AppSettings.openLocationSettings();
                  AppSettings.openNotificationSettings();
                  //  openWIFISettings();
                },
)
```

**For Java**

To open the settings for a specific channel, you can use **ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
        .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName())
        .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, yourChannelId);
startActivity(intent);
```

Using **ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS** will open settings of list all channels of the app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
        .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

For Notification check, you can use "areNotificationEnabled" method.
You can read at below doc/
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html#areNotificationsEnabled()

Comment: I am working on flutter(dart) not java , the above code is for java what i want is for flutter or dart programming language

Comment: I have updated the answer for flutter development.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer as it works for both Android and Flutter as you have tagged the question. @OlanaKenea